# Can't get Entity Framework MVC app to seed data to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am admittedly going a little bit crazy on the subject, so bear with me.  I've been attempting to do this for about 5 hours now, and I'm pretty much just banging my head against the wall at this point.  Here is what I have:

Global.asax.cs

```cs
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
        }
    }
}
```

MyInitializer.cs

```cs
namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
        {
            // seed data goes here
            sample_data = new List<MyModel>
            {
                new MyModel{"foo"},
                new MyModel{"bar"}
            };

            sample_data.ForEach(s => context.MyModels.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

MyContext.cs

```cs
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext() : base("MyContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MyInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Web.config

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=MyContext; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyContext.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <contexts>
        <context type="MyApp.Models.MyContext, MyApp">
            <databaseInitializer type="MyApp.App_Start.MyInitializer, MyApp" />
        </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
```

I just cannot figure out why it's not seeding any of the data.  I've read through the dozen or more similar cases here and elsewhere, tried just about every iteration, and still can't get it to trigger at all.  It never even hits the Seed() function.  The database exists, and if I remove it, it is rebuilt, but never populated.

I'm leaning towards there being a problem with my web.config, but I haven't figured it out yet.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using migrations? See here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Did you add your seed code to the right class? Your code says "new MyInitializer()" but the name of the class you show is PropertyInitializer

Comment: @Sam Fixed that.  Just a transcribe error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this.  Apparently, the issue was two-fold.

1. The "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" in the initializer wasn't firing, as it didn't see that the model had changed.  Changing this to "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" worked, but would usually result in a "Cannot drop database because it is currently in use" error message.  A manual disconnect of databases and restart of VS usually resolved this, though I still usually had to run it 2-3 times.  Once it dropped and rebuilt the database, reverting to "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" is faster and still works.
2. I may have been missing a line in my Web.config

   ```
   <appSettings>
       <add key="MyInitializer MyApp.Models.MyContext, MyApp.Models" value="MyApp.App_Start.MyInitializer, MyApp.Models" />
   </appSettings>
   ```

Between these two things [well, more like 4 things], it seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm), the DbInitializer isn't called until you actually try to access the database.

```
// Code copied from linked blog
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BlogContext>());
    using (var db = new BlogContext()) //initializer won't be called here
    {
        ...
        db.Categories.Add(cat); //initializer will be called here
        db.BlogPosts.Add(post);
        ...
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble transcribing between MVC apps and non-MVC apps.  As I'm not wanting to individually add each item in the Global.asax.cs file, how does this help me?  I thought the point of the Seed override was so that you didn't have to do this?

Comment: The Seed override is so that when the database is first accessed by the dbContext, it can have special handling. In your example code, you never actually did anything that required a round trip to the DB.